# Call Firefox helper functions from JS

Tags: javascript, firefox

Firefox Web Console offers a screenshot [helper function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands):

```
:screenshot --selector '#element-id' --dpr 1
```

Probably a silly question, but is it possible to call this function from JavaScript at my website? Say, I have some button and it calls this:

```
function downloadScreenshot()
{
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') === -1)
    { alert("Firefox-only"); return; }

    eval(":screenshot --selector '#element-id' --dpr 1");
}
```

If I try to run this I naturally get `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'`.

So is there some way to call Firefox Web Console API (or whatever) from JS and "tell" it to execute the screenshot command?

Firefox Developer Edition 63.0b10 (64-bit).

I reckon, it is not possible. One of the reasons would be that "malicious" scripts at websites could spam your disc with screenshots taken every millisecond.

Comment: are you using v 62+?

Comment: Yes, 63.0b10 (64-bit).

Comment: apparently eval does not recognize strings staring with colon as an expression, so do you really need eval?

Comment: First I put it into my code without `eval`, but result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Those helper functions are executed in a totally different context then a web page, with totally different privileges. Here the source code: https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/add2a1f849ecf0f7f681983e0aa35d0346d58091/devtools/shared/screenshot/save.js

So from a web page, you don't have access to them.

The only way to have a similar functionality, is create your own add-on that take the screenshot. Then, from your website, you can check if the add-on is installed, and send to it the command to take the screenshot.